# Queuing a large number of elements that show and hide for a specified number of seconds

Tags: jquery, queue

I am building a demo chat app (with jQuery) which should act like a normal chat app with a profile pic, animated typing bubble and the message bubble. All of these must be visible at the specified time to make the app look authentic.
For this Im using show, hide and delay which is turning out to be less than ideal as all the stages of the app are queued in seconds making fault finding difficult.
What i'd like to do is to put these in a function so they can be called and queued individually so i don't have the risk of random elements firing and messing up the order.

```
function chat1() {
    $('div#chat1').queue(function () {
      $(this).show(0);
      $('div.chat1.jonProfile').show(0);
      $('div.chat1.bubble.jonBubble').hide(0).delay(3000).show(0); 
      $('div.chat1.chat-bubble.left').show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);
    });
    $('div#chat1').dequeue();
    chat2();
  }

  function chat2() {
    $('div#chat2').queue(function () {
      $(this).show(0);
      $('div.chat2.bubble.jonBubble').hide(0).delay(7000).show(0);
      $('div.chat2.chat-bubble.left').hide(0).delay(7000).show(0).delay(3000).hide(0); 
    });
    $('div#chat2').dequeue();
    chat3();
  }

  function chat3() {
    $('div#chat3').queue(function () {
      $(this).show(0);
      $('div.chat3.julieProfile').hide(0).delay(10000).show(0);
      $('div.chat3.chat-bubble.right').hide(0).delay(10000).show(0).delay(3000).hide(0);
      $('div.chat3.bubble.julieBubble').hide(0).delay(13000).show(0);
    });
    $('div#chat3').dequeue();
  }
```

This is what i'm working at the moment. As mentioned above i'd rather call the chat2 function when the chat1 function has completely finished.

Please let me know if theres a better way of doing this. Thanks

Comment: @adeneo Ah yeah good point. Just left those comments in there, but it seems i have to add the seconds from chat1 in to chat2.

Comment: Anyway, you can make the functions return a deferred object that is resolved when the animations are complete, or just use a callback.

Comment: @adeneo any chance you could add a quick example please?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/qdkcm8b4/

Comment: Thanks @adeneo I will give that a go

Comment: I seem to be getting "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" @adeneo